# Jquery mouse enter and mouse leave not working on li element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery mouse enter and mouse leave functions . 
this is my code : 
html :

```
    <ul class="menuList bold">
      <li id="tevee">
        <span>test</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
  $(".tevee").on("mouseenter",".menuList",hoverInFunction());

  $(".tevee").mouseleave(hoverOutFunction("tevee"));

});

function hoverInFunction()
{
  alert("hi")
}

function hoverOutFunction(variable)
{
  alert("test");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tejareddy/dndvsudh/ . this is my fiddle , they are not working instead they are triggering on page load and not every time when i hover on them .

Comment: `()` will invoke the function...You need to pass expression of function..

Comment: Dot selector is used to select element with class. You gave id, so use # selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your selector was incorrect for the ".on" call, secondly, you were using parenthesis when referring to a function (which in this case must be referred to as an object without the parenthesis).

```
$(function(){
    $(".menuList").on("mouseenter","li",hoverInFunction);

    $(".menuList").on("mouseleave","li",hoverOutFunction);

})
```

Please see the fixed version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dndvsudh/1/)

You may use `event.data` if you wish to pass parameters into the calls.

The original method of binding the event to the ID is not what .on is all about, it's best to bind to a higher-level object in the DOM (such as the actual menuList) and then write a selector which will affect the children on it. That way you get "delegated eventing" and any dynamically added items will still work the way you want them to.

Comment: thank you , i did not knew that hiverInfunction() will initiate it .

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `()`

change

```
$(function(){
  $("#tevee").on("mouseenter",".menuList",hoverInFunction());

});
```

to:

```
$(function(){
  $("#tevee").on("mouseenter",".menuList",hoverInFunction)

});
```

or do it like this:

```
    $("#tevee").on("mouseenter",".menuList",function(){
    alert("hi")
    }).on("mouseleave",".menuList", function(){   
  alert("test");
});
```

Comment: @JeffWatkins, Thanks I copied and used his code from question and didn't recognize it.